# Insert to text file from PHP-generated inputs

Tags: php, function, text

I am stuck on a problem for a PHP assignment I have. I created a PHP script to generate form inputs, and I must take the data from the input and insert it into a text document. So I wrote the code that generates two inputs and a function that will write the data to the text document. However, my text document appears blank. How would I properly define a function that takes multiple values from text inputs and inserts them into a text document? Here is my code so far:

```
<form method='post'> 
<table border='0' cellpadding='3' cellspacing='5'>
  <tr>
    <td><h2>Item</h2></td>
    <td><h2>Amount</h2></td>
  </tr>
<?php

for($row=1; $row<5;$row++)
    {

    $item_name='item_name'.$row;    
    $item_value = $_POST[$item_name];

    $amount_name='amount_name'.$row;    
    $amount_value = $_POST[$amount_name];



echo 
"<tr>
    <td><input type='text' name='$item_name' value='$item_value'  /></td>
    <td><input type='text' name='$amount_name' value='$amount_value' /></td>
";  

    if (!empty($amount_value))
    {
            if(is_numeric($amount_value))
            {
            $total = $total + $amount_value;
            }
            else {
        echo    
            "<td class='bad'>Amount Invalid: $amount_value</td>";
            $error_count++;
            }
    }


echo"   
  </tr>
";

    }
?>  

<tr>
    <td colspan='2'>
    <input name='' type='submit' value='Submit' />
    </td>
</table>
<?php
    if ($error_count > 0)
    {
    echo "<br /><span class='bad' />Errors: $error_count</span>";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "<br />Total: $total";
    }
    if ($error_count == 0)
    {
    addData();
    }


    //Function
    function addData()
    {
    $myFile = "bills.txt";
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
    $stringData = $amount_value;
    fwrite($fh, $stringData);
    $stringData = $item_value;
    fwrite($fh, $stringData);
    fclose($fh);
    }   

?>
</form>
```

Comment: Add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` on top of your script. Then consider adding function parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you assign a value to `$item_value` at the top of the code, you are creating a variable called $item_value within the scope of your php tag. In the function addData(), there is no variable called $item_value, so `$stringData = $item_value` creates a variable `$stringData` with a value equal to the new variable `item_value` with a value of null. Pass the data to your method then you will be able to access it.

Try calling it like:

```
addData($item_value);
```

Then change the method to:

```
function addData($item_value){
```

Comment: OK, I went ahead and tried this, but the text document is blank. Also, would I need to define both variables? ($item_value and $amount_value)?

Comment: Then I don't think you are ever getting to call the method `addData` because  `if ($error_count == 0)` is returning false. Try adding `echo 'ERROR COUNT = 0';` to the code right about the line `addData($item_value)`. If nothing displays you know that you're never getting to call the method either.

Comment: Hmm, I added it in and it displayed

Comment: So basically I'm trying to figure out why these values are displaying as null

Comment: Try the same thing as before, except now try `echo $item_value`. If something is displayed then you know $item_value isn't empty. The scope of the variable might be ending in the first set of <?php ?> tags.

Answer (score 1):

PHP's variable scope rules do not allow global variables to appear within a function, unless you explicitly declare them global. So within your `addData()` function, $amount_value and $item_value are both undeclared/undefined LOCAL variables, and get converted to nulls/empty strings for the fwrite() calls, so you code can only ever write out an empty file.

Either pass the values as function parameters:

```
addData($amount_value, $item_value);
```

or declare them as globals:

```
function addData() {
   global $amount_value, $item_value
```

Of the two, go with the parameter version. Global variables are messy.

Comment: I've tried both methods, but I just get a blank text document everytime

Comment: Don't forget that you're actually loading 5 different sets of POSt data into those two vars. Only the last set will "stick", and if those were submitted empty, then you get empty variables.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to pass `$amount_value` and `$item_value` in to the function, at least. And probably some carriage returns. e.g.

```
addData($item_value, $amount_value);

//Function
function addData($item_value, $amount_value)
{
    $myFile = "bills.txt";
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
    fwrite($fh, "$amount_value, $item_value\n");
    fclose($fh);
}
```

Comment: Well I did this and my text doc was empty. Any ideas? Will it be ok if the values are in quotes like this: fwrite($fh, "$amount_value, $item_value\n")?

Comment: You probably want the `a` mode for opening the file. That will append to the file (`w` will overwrite each time). See [fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) for more information. The quotes are OK because PHP interpolates variables in double quotes (i.e. it replaces `$amount_value` with its actual value, such as `4`).